# Проект на laravel перестал запускаться локально

Tags: laravel, openserver

Всем привет. У меня есть созданный проект, который я до этого дня нормально запускал локально на openserver. Но сегодня при запуске командой в консоли: `php artisan serve` выдает ошибку:

```
Fatal error: composerRequired60449d8a9a3d7f37865488b9b7c4d70(): Failed opening required 'C:\OpenServer\domains\laravel3\vendor\composer/../../app/helpers.php' (include_path='.') in C:\OpenServer\domains\laravel3\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 71
```

пробовал `composer update` - тоже самая ошибка выходит.Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Попробуй `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @Knyaz71, спасибо за ответ, но эта команда выдает туже ошибку

Comment: Проблему нашел. Проблема была в пути /app/helpers.php, но при установке файл находится по  пути /app/Helpers/helpers.php. Я файл helpers вынес из папки Helpers. Незнаю правильно это или нет, но других вариантов не нашел)

Comment: Это не правильно (хотя правил так-то и нет..), в composer.json просто путь поменять нужно на корректный